# New attribute created in admin side is not showing in storefront UI in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created a new attribute (which is a multi select drop-down) and added to attribute set. When I edit or create a product in admin, that newly created attribute is found there and I can select the values and save.

So It is supposed to show in user front end side. But that's not showing there in the product detail page. It still shows only color and size.

In product attribute sections I have enabled 
"Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" to "Yes" and
"Used in Product Listing" to "Yes"

Is there any settings which I have to accomplish the same?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after adding the attribute?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: yes. All cache are disabled

Comment: @ArunSS have you found a solution to this? What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do an indexing process using the command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Then clear your cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Database and set is visible to 1

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `is_visible` = '1' WHERE `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = YourAttributeId;
```